# Passing the alias databricks provider - terraform

Tags: terraform, azure-databricks, hashicorp

Sorry for the very long code. I want to create the group on the account level and also deploy SQL warehouses on workspace level. I understand that I need to pass two different providers in this case (`alias`) but I'm doing it wrong, I suppose.

I have the following structure where I keep all the terraform files:

```
├── dev/
    └── groups.auto.tfvars
    └── sql_warehouses.auto.tfvars
    └── main.tf
    └── variable.tf
├── modules/
    └── main.tf
    └── locals.tf
    └── variable.tf
    └── databricks_groups.tf
    └── databricks_sql_warehouses.tf
    resources/
         groups/
          └── main.tf
          └── module.tf
          └── variables.tf
         sql_warehouses/
          └── main.tf
          └── module.tf
          └── variables.tf
```

Let me present what I have in each file.

So from the top `dev/`:

**main.tf**

```
terraform {
  backend "azurerm" {
    # container_name = "databricks"
    key            = "terraform.tfstate"
  }
  required_providers {
    databricks = {
      source  = "databricks/databricks"
      version = "1.23.0"
    }
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "3.35.0"
    }
  }
}
locals {
  tenant_id       = var.tenant_id
  subscription_id = var.subscription_id
}
# PROVIDER REGISTRATION
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
  storage_use_azuread        = false
  skip_provider_registration = true
  tenant_id                  = local.tenant_id
  subscription_id            = local.subscription_id
}

provider "databricks" {
  azure_workspace_resource_id = 
 data.azurerm_databricks_workspace.workspace.id
  host                        = 
data.azurerm_databricks_workspace.workspace.workspace_url
}

locals {
  account_id       = var.tenant_id
}
provider "databricks" {
  alias      = "azure_account"
  host       = "https://accounts.azuredatabricks.net"
  account_id = var.account_id
  auth_type  = "azure-cli"
}
module "this" {
  source = "../modules"

  # tags            = var.tags
  global_settings = var.global_settings
  databricks = {
    databricks_sql_warehouse           = 
  var.databricks_sql_warehouse
    databricks_groups                  = var.databricks_groups
  }
}
```

Then we go to `modules/`

**main.tf**

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "~> 3.35.0"
    }
    azuread = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azuread"
      version = "~> 2.22.0"
    }
    databricks = {
      source  = "databricks/databricks"
      version = "1.23.0"
      configuration_aliases = databricks.azure_account 
    }
  }
}
data "azurerm_subscription" "primary" {}
data "azurerm_client_config" "current" {}
```

**local.tf**

```
locals {
    databricks = {
        databricks_groups = 
  try(var.databricks.databricks_groups, {})
        databricks_sql_warehouse = 
  try(var.databricks.databricks_sql_warehouse, {})
    }
  }
```

**databricks_groups.tf**

```
  module "databricks_groups" {
  source   = "./modules/groups"
  for_each = local.databricks.databricks_groups

  settings = each.value

  providers = {
    databricks =databricks.azure_account
  }
  }
```

then we going inside `resources` and there I have `groups` folder with files:

**main.tf**

```
terraform {
required_providers {
databricks = {
  source  = "databricks/databricks"
  version = "1.23.0"
  configuration_aliases = databricks.azure_account 
}
}
}
```

and my **module.tf** looks like this

```
resource "databricks_group" "this" {
  provider     = databricks.azure_account
  display_name = var.settings.aad_groups
}
```

Could you please help me to identify where I'm making a mistake?

My error points to `main.tf` file in the `modules` folder

> configuration_aliases = databricks.azure_account
> A static list expression is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When Terraform says "a static list expression", it means a series of expressions in brackets `[` `]`, separated by commas `,`.

You only have one configuration alias to specify, so you don't need any commas but you do still need the brackets to satisfy the requirement that it be a "static list expression":

```
  configuration_aliases = [databricks.azure_account]
```

---

Fixing this one syntax error may reveal other problems, since the syntax error will be blocking Terraform from starting semantic validation. If so, I suggest starting a new question about that because Stack Overflow's Q&A format does not really work for answering follow-up questions.

Comment: Do you agree what Tim said in the answer about my configuration_aliases